# Camel : How to set matchOnUriPrefix=true for jetty component configured in <restConfiguration>

Tags: apache-camel

I have following camel routing configuration.

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

<!-- Rest Configuration -->
<restConfiguration component="jetty" port="9092" bindingMode="auto">
    <dataFormatProperty key="json.in.disableFeatures" value="FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES" />
</restConfiguration>

<rest path="/" consumes="application/json"
        produces="application/json">
        <post uri="/" type="com.aaa.xxxx.esb.config.xxxxEsbJsonMapping">
            <route>
                <setHeader headerName="Authorization">
                    <simple>Basic YWRtaXXXXWRtaW4=</simple>
                </setHeader>
                <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
                    <constant>POST</constant>
                </setHeader>

                <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
                    <constant>POST</constant>
                </setHeader>

                <setHeader headerName="RestEndpointURL">
                    <simple>
                        http://${body.serviceURL}?bridgeEndpoint=true
                    </simple>
                </setHeader>
                <setBody>
                    <simple>{"UserDetails": ${body.serviceDataJsonObj}}</simple>
                </setBody>

                <log message="Exchanged headers : ${headers.RestEndpointURL}" />

                <recipientList>
                    <simple>${headers.RestEndpointURL}</simple>
                </recipientList>

            </route>
        </post>
    </rest>
```

What I need to know is where I can set

> matchOnUriPrefix=true

option for the jetty component which I have already configured for camel rest.

According to the Claus Ibsen answer, I changed configuration XML as follows.

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <!-- Rest Configuration -->
    <restConfiguration component="jetty" port="9092"
        bindingMode="auto">
        <dataFormatProperty key="json.in.disableFeatures"
            value="FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES" />
        <componentProperty key="matchOnUriPrefix" value="true" />
    </restConfiguration>

    <!-- Rest Services -->
<rest path="/" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
        <post uri="/" type="com.aaa.xxxx.esb.config.xxxxEsbJsonMapping">
            <route>
                <setHeader headerName="Authorization">
                    <simple>Basic YWRXXX46YWRtaW4=</simple>
                </setHeader>
                <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
                    <constant>POST</constant>
                </setHeader>

                <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
                    <constant>POST</constant>
                </setHeader>

                <setHeader headerName="RestEndpointURL">
                    <simple>
                        http://${body.serviceURL}?bridgeEndpoint=true
                    </simple>
                </setHeader>
                <setBody>
                    <simple>{"SystemUserDetails": ${body.serviceDataJsonObj}}</simple>
                </setBody>

                <log message="Exchanged headers : ${headers.RestEndpointURL}" />

                <recipientList>
                    <simple>${headers.RestEndpointURL}</simple>
                </recipientList>

            </route>
        </post>
    </rest>

</camelContext>
```

I'm using servicemix apache-servicemix-7.0.0.M2
I upgraded its camel ver 2.16.3 to 2.17.3

Thanks

Comment: These are my xml namespaces  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                  http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
                  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

Comment: Exception: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 33 in XML document from URL [bundle://365.0:0/META-INF/spring/camel.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'componentProperty'. One of '{"http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":dataFormatProperty, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":apiProperty, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":corsHeaders}' is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rest-dsl is configured using the `componentProperty` in the `restConfiguration`:

```
<restConfiguration component="jetty" port="9092" bindingMode="auto">
    <componentProperty key="matchOnUriPrefix" value="true"/>
    <dataFormatProperty key="json.in.disableFeatures" value="FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES" />
</restConfiguration>
```

You can find details about this in the documentation: http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl

Comment: Thanks Claus, I tried it but I am getting following XML parse exception Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'componentProperty'. One of '{"http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":dataFormatProperty, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":apiProperty, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":corsHeaders}' is expected. I am using camel-2.16.3

Comment: Try with a newer Camel version such as 2.17.3

Comment: Thanks @Claus I have upgraded camel from 2.16.3 to 2.17.3 but I still get the same exception. I have included the xml namespaces as a comment in my question. Can you please look into that. I think we are close to the answer.

Comment: Run/test it outside ServiceMix as its likely something wrong with ServiceMix / OSGi. And make sure to use all the same version of your Camel JARs as it contains the XSD schema that is being used.

Comment: Thanks Claus, I found a way to make it work. I don't weather it is the standard or not. There should be an proper order among the elements inside <restConfiguration>. <componentProperty> actually it should be <endpointProperty> should come before the <dataFormatProperty>

Comment: According to the http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd I guess proper order is componentProperty, endpointProperty, consumerProperty, dataFormatProperty, apiProperty, corsHeaders. If you are agree with this behavior I can mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Yeah the XSD has an order you must configure accordingly. Its standard XSD.

Comment: Please correct the answer then I can mark it as the correct answer. It will be helpful for someone else. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

U may add inside
**route**

tag as below:

```
<route>
  <from uri="jetty://foo?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
  ...
</route>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here I am using jetty component and are you saying me to configure as <from uri="jetty://foo?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>